# Is there an easy way of finding nonrepeating groups of subsets of a set?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, combinatorics

Let's say I have a set: `{1,2,...,N}`, and I want to find nonrepeating groups of K nonempty subsets with specific number of elements in each subset.

E.g.: Set: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` number of subsets `3`, number of elements `3,3,1`. This would generate groups like: `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7}} or {{5,7,2},{4,3,1},{6}}` etc.

The number of all possible groups, in this case, is equal to `C(7,3)*C(4,3)*C(1,1)*1/(2!) = 35*4/2 = 70`

If I were to generate the first combination and then the second one, I would get 140 outcomes, because this method would not factor in the factorial.

**So my question is:** Is there an easy way of checking if a group has showed up already? Would I need to create an array with all the previously calculated groups and check each time if the new one has already been generated?

Comment: "I want to find nonrepeating groups" - do you mean you'd like to list the nonrepeating groups? Could you give an example of a "repeating" group (the kind you'd prefer not to find)?

Comment: @גלעד ברקן Sure, an example of two repeating groups for a set {1,2,3,4,5}, number of subsets 3, number of elements 2,2,1, would be: {{1,2},{3,4},{5}} and {{3,4},{1,2},{5}}. But I figured it out! Here is my solution: cpp.sh/67lwt What it does: it lists all sets that make up any stirling number of the second kind S{n,k} and writes out the number of all these sets (value of S{n,k}). The input consists of two positive integers n and k, where n>=k. The source code is atrocious, but hey, I'm pretty new to programming and it works, so it's enough to make me happy! Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate all of the groups, but only keep a group if subsets of equal size appear in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

For example, you would keep the group `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7}}` because `{1,2,3}` precedes `{4,5,6}` in lexicographical order.

However, you would discard the group `{{5,7,2},{4,3,1},{6}}` because `{5,7,2}` should follow `{4,3,1}`. The theory is that at some point you'll generate the group `{{4,3,1},{5,7,2},{6}}` which is in the correct order, and therefore will be kept.

---

The next level of optimization is to *not* generate all of the groups, but only generate groups that are lexicographically correct. For example, if the first subset is `{5,7,2}`, then the second subset must be of the form `{6,x,y}` since `6` is the only unused number greater than `5`.